# Codeigniter - Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou usando o CI na versão 2.2.5 e estou com um erro no meu projeto.

> Erro: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\
>
> local: system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php on line 77

Função do arquivo, da linha 77 `mysqli_driver.php`

```
function db_connect()
{
    if ($this->port != '') {
        return @mysqli_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database, $this->port);
    } else {
        return @mysqli_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);
    }
}
```

Estou usando o php 7.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso? Obrigado

Detalhe: eu já habilitei o meu `extension=php_mysqli.dll` no **php.ini**

No arquivo **config/database.php** eu já alterei para `$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';`

porem o erro continua

Comment: Provavelmente a extensao do mysqli não está ativa no seu php, verifique no php.ini